# restart ssh in solaris

Tags: ssh, solaris

I have added file with `env.variable` in `.ssh/environment`

How to restart `ssh` now, so this change will be reflected.

Answer (score 3):

To restart the SSH service

```
svcadm restart ssh
```

however you may need to log in again (i.e. restart your session) to reload the environment variables.

Comment: I'm using solaris 10 ...seems like there is no "service command" available ...

Comment: I *believe* the `service` command is only on RHEL

Comment: Not thinking entirely straight :) Answer updated

Answer (score 2):

`~/.ssh/environment` is read at login time. Just open another session after you have changed the file. If it is not working then you need to add into your sshd_config the following line:
PermitUserEnvironment="yes"
then restart sshd. To restart ssh you either have a ascript in /etc/init.d or you have `svcs` and `svcadm` command

You can also add your environment variables to `~/.login` file. And if your default shell is bash you can add them to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I have added the entry in LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /.ssh/enviroment and 
modifed sshd_config and restarted the ssh using svcadm .. but after login env doesn't show the LD_LIBRARY_PATH value.

Comment: Do not forget `PermitUserEnvironment="yes"` in `sshd_config`. It is no by default. This means that it is not reading your file.

Comment: Do you have any reason why you are not using `.login` or `.bashrc` to change the environment?

Comment: I'm trying to launch SSH without opening a session  http://www.raphink.info/2008/09/forcing-environment-in-ssh.html